# Create CANNON body from THREE. Mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js, cannon.js

I have a THREE.js plane that the points are moved up and down using Perlin noise to make terrain. Now I need to add physics to the camera to stop it from just falling through the plane.

I'm hoping to make a function that can retrieve the vertices and faces out of the mesh and copy them over to a CANNON body as a Convex Polyhedron. Here's what I have so far but doesn't work:

```
function setPhysicsGeometry(mesh, body) {
    const vertices = mesh.geometry.vertices;
    const shape = new CANNON.ConvexPolyhedron();

    vertices.forEach(function(vertex) {
        // Adjust vertex position based on the physics properties
        vertex.z = 0; // Assuming initial z position is 0

        // Add the vertex to the shape
        shape.vertices.push(new CANNON.Vec3(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z));
    });

    // Compute the faces of the shape
    const faces = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < mesh.geometry.faces.length; i++) {
        const face = mesh.geometry.faces[i];
        faces.push([face.a, face.b, face.c]);
    }
    shape.faces = faces;

    // Update the shape's bounding box
    shape.updateNormals();
    shape.updateEdges();

    // Assign the shape to the body
    body.addShape(shape);
}
```

This is an error that I get:
`Uncaught TypeError: shape.updateNormals is not a function`

Same thing happens for shape.updateEdges()

Is this a problem with those two functions or am I over simplifying something that is difficult/impossible.

Thanks

UPDATE:
I have made a function that sort of works but its super slow:

```
function createShape(geo) {
    const bufferedGeo = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geo); // Turn geometry into buffer geo

    let position = bufferedGeo.attributes.position.array
    const points = []

    for (let i = 0; i < position.length; i += 3) {
        points.push(new CANNON.Vec3(position[i], position[i + 1], position[i + 2]))
    }
    const faces = []
    
    for (let i = 0; i < position.length / 3; i += 3) {
        faces.push([i, i + 1, i + 2])
    }

    const shape = new CANNON.ConvexPolyhedron(points, faces)
    
    return shape
}
```

Here is an error I get that shows that the normals are being ordered in the wrong order:

`.faceNormals[1011] = Vec3(-0.38237948261368415,0.4673447646702331,-0.7971040096570934) looks like it points into the shape? The vertices follow. Make sure they are ordered CCW around the normal, using the right hand rule.`

I don't know how to fix it since they are just taken from the geometry

Comment: I found an example using a torusKnot, maybe it can help? It uses a CANNON.Trimesh object and copies the geometry, not the verticies. 
 https://sbedit.net/cfc3121bcf3f13fe27d426be3d50876f29a6c683

Comment: That does look like it could work. Although when I copy and pasted the "CreateTrimesh()" function into my code the page doesn't load at all soo I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. The mesh is a plane but I don't know if that's whats wrong with it

Comment: Correction: I've just discovered that the trimesh is not able to collide with anything. A test shows that it just goes right through the floor for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm at a loss for experience on that.  Can you maybe try, in a similar fashion to copy the geometry, rather than the vertices?

Comment: I've discovered that you need a buffer geometry to get the attributes like the normals vertices and faces.  I've made a function that actually works but its so unbelievably slow when a collision occurs but instead of using Trimesh it uses the convex polyhedron. I'm going to add the function that I made to the original question because it says the faces are ordered in the wrong order or something

Answer (score 2):

I solved it (Not completely, still bugs with the physics but that's a different problem).

Thanks to [This Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11985062/this-guy) for sending me an amazing example of where I got the solution from. I was attempting to use ConvexPolyhedron to get my own body shape. I think it is still possible to do that but ordering the faces and normals in the correct syntax is really difficult. Instead, I used Trimesh which was much simpler.

However, in the example, he used `new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry()` and then went straight into `createTrimesh()`. For me this would return an error because the THREE.js geometry was not a buffer geometry. So I changed with a simple function and it returned no errors. Still physics wouldn't work on the object. So after what felt like two long I copied the position and quartation from the THREE.js mesh to the CANNON body and it works pretty well. Here is the completed code:

Code to Copy position and quartation

```
function copy(threeMesh, cannonBody) {
    // Copy position
    const position = new CANNON.Vec3(
        threeMesh.position.x,
        threeMesh.position.y,
        threeMesh.position.z
    );
    cannonBody.position.copy(position);

    // Copy rotation
    const quaternion = new CANNON.Quaternion(
        threeMesh.quaternion.x,
        threeMesh.quaternion.y,
        threeMesh.quaternion.z,
        threeMesh.quaternion.w
    );
    cannonBody.quaternion.copy(quaternion);
}
```

Code to create Trimesh:

```
function buffer(geo) {
    const bufferedGeo = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geo);
    return bufferedGeo;
}

function CreateTrimesh(geometry) {
    const vertices = buffer(geometry).attributes.position.array
    const indices = Object.keys(vertices).map(Number)
    return new CANNON.Trimesh(vertices, indices)
}
```

And Mesh and Body code:

```
var platformGeometry = createCustomGeometry(terrain, size + 1, size + 1)
var platformMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00, wireframe: false, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
var platform = new THREE.Mesh(platformGeometry, platformMaterial);
platform.receiveShadow = true;
platform.castShadow = true
platform.position.set(0, 0, 0)
platform.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2
scene.add(platform);

var platShape = CreateTrimesh(platformGeometry, platform)
var platBody = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 0, shape: platShape });
copy(platform, platBody)
world.addBody(platBody)
```